# Difference between across and beyond?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, prepositions, idioms

Is there any difference between the two ideas:

"She came from Spencer, **across** the hill"
"She came from Spencer, **beyond** the hill"

It sounds to me that across is more near of the hill than beyond, but I'm not sure.

Comment: In my opinion, your context is not really that clear (though it's obvious that the first one is from a song named Tecumseh Valley). As it's written (with a comma), I can read the first sentence at least two ways: *She came across the hill*, *She came from across the hill (and the place that she came from was Spencer)*. The phrase *beyond the hill* in the second sentence looks like an appositive to me, that is *She came from Spencer (which was) beyond the hill*.

Comment: @DamkerngT. it's really from Tecumseh Valley :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll address on *this context* and not other uses of 'beyond/across'.

In laypersons' language, 'beyond' has a connection with 'far'. So, if you are telling that someone is going 'beyond' something, you **mark** the hill as a point to describe what went farther.

[OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/beyond_1?q=beyond) example says:

> *The road continues beyond the village up into the hills.* -the village is the mark and the road goes **farther** into the hills.

On the other hand, 'across' talks about two points and in between is your object. So, if something is coming 'across' the hill, it's passing by the hill or getting 'through' it.

> To get *across* the hill, you need great stamina. It's almost 45 km, you know!

Here, I'm taking two points -from where we are standing and I'm speaking **and** to cross the hill and go *beyond* it!

---

Somehow, I feel that 'came' fits better with 'across'; 'beyond' is generally observed with 'go'. However, there could be exceptions but what I said is 'general'.